# Replacing Production App - Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am trying to replace a deleted Heroku app that was my production location. When I run "git push production master", I now get the following:

remote: !       No such app as arcane-ocean-9502.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/arcane-ocean-9502.git/' not found

How do I replace this?

"git push staging master" works just fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've deleted the app from Heroku, of course you can't push anymore: there's nothing to push to! Create a new Heroku app called `arcane-ocean-9502`, or create an app called something else and update your remote to point to the new app, *then* push.

Comment: Right. How do I update my remote to point to another/new app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways I can see fixing this.  The simplest is probably to just remove and then readd your remote that points to the correct app. This should tell you how to do that: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

The other way you could do this is by manually editing the git config file and changing the URL for your remote to the correct new one.  To do this, start at the root of your git repo and cd into the .git directory.  Then just update the remote listed in the config file in that directory

Comment: Thanks, I was able to set a new app!

Comment: @lluis If this solved your problem, would you mind marking it as the best answer?